# Evince application on Windows 2012R2 RDP not printing

Tags: redirect, printing, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

I have an Windows 2012R2 server. I connect to that server using RDP. When I start Evince.exe (a pdf viewer program) everything works fine, except for printing to the redirected printer. If I print, I get the standard printer dialog and it shows my redirected printer. When I print a pdf document using the redirected printer, I can see the job appearing in the printer queue for just a second and then disappearing again. But no printing occurs.

If I print to the Microsoft XPS printer, a .xps file is created properly. If I print a notepad using the redirected printer, it works fine. So the problem is purely with the redirected printer and Evince.

What could be the cause of this issue? I have tried to reset the printer spooler already using this in een elevated command prompt :

```
net stop spooler
DEL /F /S /Q %systemroot%\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*
net start spooler
```

But it still does not print. The Windows event logs show no errors or warnings.
Anyone have an idea how to solve this issue? Could it be a permissions issue?

Comment: Try running Evince as Admin and see if that helps diagnose permissions

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. In the meantime I found that this issue is only with my personal account or pc. All my users can print using Evince and they have no admin privileges like me. The weird thing is, the print queue gets emptied on the server, but my pc does not receive the print job in the queue somehow. This only happens for Evince print jobs and not for any other print jobs. I tried to reboot both the server and my personal pc. There are no weird log entries on the server nor on my pc.

I tried to redirect another printer (Microsoft print to PDF printer) and that works fine. So the problem is with my HP laser printer. But why only for Evince print jobs???  I really have no clue what is causing this. Maybe my printer driver is corrupt somehow. I can try to reinstall my printer on my PC, maybe that will do the trick. I will try later this week because currently I am too busy to make time for this.

BR, Emphyrio